# Magento Fedex currency

Tags: magento, currency, fedex

Conditions:

1. We need the default display currency in our Magento site be USD, and the Paypal (base currency) also needed to be USD (because we need customers to pay in USD).
2. Our Fedex a/c is opened in Singapore it turns out that the shipping amount is billed in Singapore Dollar.

Here is the problem:

If the product is sold at USD 200 and actual Fedex shipping amount is (Singapore Dollar)SGD 100, Magento will treat this shipping amount as USD 100 making the final total amount to USD 300 while it should be acutally around USD 278.

I tried to change the base currency in Magento to SGD and everything were calculated correctly (into USD). But the problem is this makes our customers make all payments in SGD by Paypal/credit card. We want our customers to pay USD.

Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

Comment: Is the  shipping amount calculated through api or is stored in table rates in backend of magento?

Comment: through Fedex's api by entering the a/c no. meter no. etc.

Comment: @user3180935 Which extension is used for fedex?

Answer (score 0):

Below module can solve your problem.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-currency-payment-checkout.html

Use SGD as base currency and USD as Default Display Currency on store. This module enable charge user with the currency shown in the cart i.e USD.